# How to correctly implement iAds? iOS6 deprecation issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, iad

I'm currently trying to add iAd to my app, I've come across a couple of tutorials and have the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 460.0f);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate = self;
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
```

Problem is I get warnings for `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers`, `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `currentContentSizeIdentifier` because they're now deprecated and my ads do not load.

I've had a mooch at the Apple docs and they seem to be mentioning the same things so I'm confused.

How is it supposed to be correctly implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `createAdBannerView` method just comment the lines using `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers`, `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `currentContentSizeIdentifier` etc.. And hard code the adBanner frame as below(for iPhone Portrait):

```
[_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 320,
                                         -[self getBannerHeight])];
```

Check your ad load or not.. Its worked for me...(But my app is only supporting the portrait view, and its worked)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add iAds in iOS6 then you have to implement following code.

```
self.iAddBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 768, 1024, 66)];
[self.iAddBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.view addSubview:self.iAddBannerView];
self.iAddBannerView.delegate = self;
```